# Style.css in CodeIgniter PHP and Template Library

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, templates

I use [CodeIgniter Template](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template) and CodeIgniter PHP framework. I don't know how works metadata in this library (template). I try to add style.css to my layout. In User Guide I've found info:

```
 **prepend_metadata()**

Add a line to the start of the $template['metadata'] string.

    Parameters

    $line - string REQUIRED - Metadata line.
    Usage

            $this->template->prepend_metadata('<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>');
```

In my layout file I have:

```
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
<?=$template['metadata']?>
</head>
```

In Controller file:

```
 $this->template
                    ->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />')
                    ->set_layout('index');
```

It's look like good, but don't work at all.

Style.css is in views/css/style.css and layout file (index.php) is in views/css/layout/index.php.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try using href='<?=base_url()?>css/style.css'

Comment: `base_url()` + `'/directory/path/to/css'` or `base_url('directory/path/to/css')`

Comment: I tired base_url("application/views/css/style.css") or base_url()?>css/style.css and nothing ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution of my problem.

Step1: In .htcaccess file I added 'CSS' to RewtireCond

```
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
```

Step2: I created 'Assets' folder next to 'system' / 'application' folder

Step3: I have used this commend

```
->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url("assets/css/style.css").'" type="text/css" media="all" />')
```